# How to remove jMockit Fake/MockUp for abstract method?

Tags: java, junit, log4j, jmockit

Because I [can't fake an abstract class directly](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html#mockableMethods) and I know the implementing class, I added the fake to the implementing class.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void fakeCurrentYear() {
    // Mocking the abstract 'Calender' does not work, see: https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/71
    // So we use the implementing class 'GregorianCalendar'.
    new MockUp<GregorianCalendar>() {

        @Mock public int get(Invocation invocation, int field) {
            return 2016;
        }
    };
}
```

I'm using jMockit v 1.31 with JUnit 4.12 and Maven 3.x.

When I execute tests individually, everything is fine.

But when I execute all tests together, another test fails because the log4jlogger in the implementing class obviously uses the fake-implementation.

I think this is because previously `GregorianCalendar` did not overwrite that method. However, I thought the fake is automatically removed after the testclass! Is this a bug?

Can I remove it manually? I've tried stepping back to JMockit v1.25, created a static variable `yearMock = new MockUp<GregorianCalendar>() ...` and calling `yearMock.tearDown()` in a `@AfterClass` method, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used a workaround, where I created a method in the class under test with just a single line of code

```
private int currentYear4digits() {
    return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

In my test I then mocked this method.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void fakeCurrentYear() {
    new MockUp<MyClass>() {

        @Mock 
        public int currentYear4digits() {
            return 2016;
        }
    };
}
```

However, this is just a workaround. It would be cumbersome if the calls to `Calendar` where made from several classes.

Comment: I'm guessing you figured it out by now, but you shouldn't mock JDK/System classes, just your own ones.